# Django - Is there any way to generate some HTML parts on the fly without using the minidom or lxml libs?

Tags: python, html, django, dom

I am trying to generate some HTML parts in a template directly using Django and python without the Django templating Engine, is there any way to do that just with what Django offers ?

**NB:  the main reason is that I don't have a model for the data i am trying to make forms for, so using 'ModelForm' is not an option for me since it require an ORM model, witch I don't have !**

Cheers mates,

Comment: Why don't you want to use a template? That's what they're for.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the template system if you're already in a template ???

Comment: The code is in a class separated from the templates, and it is generated on the fly, I don't want to mix the template code with the logic. Also I am using Bootstrap.

Comment: Sure, you're not forced to use Django's template engine. [yattag](http://www.yattag.org) looks like the best way to do it with Python alone.

Comment: Thanks fro the suggestion, the main reason actually is that I don't have a model for the data i am trying to make forms for, so using 'ModelForm' is not an option for me since it require a ORM model !

Comment: Well, yattag seems to fit perfectly, then, since you can define the presentation of html forms with it.

Comment: I am on an embedded system, so preferably Django or standard Python libs witch is already ported and tested, I think my best option here is may be minidom or lxml !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to use Django Template Engine as @Daniel Roseman suggested. Specifically using the Forms without any bound to any Model is the solution i was looking for, here is SOF link: [Can I have a Django form without Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17754295/can-i-have-a-django-form-without-model)

Hope this can help someone in the future, Thanks all for your suggestions.