# two url one view - combining views

Tags: python, django, twitter

I am attempting to build an app that can post tweet to a users twitter account from a text area (input by the user). I cannot though figure out how to include the textarea and the login/logout functionality within the same view (and thus called from the same urlpattern).

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^$', IndexView.as_view()),
url(r'^$','twitter_login.views.form_handle'),
#other url's omitted
```

**views.py**

```
class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "index.html"

def log_out(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('/')

# cite karthikr: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17754295/can-i-have-a-django-form-without-model
def form_handle(request):
    form = MyForm()
    if request.method=='POST':
    form = MyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            text = cd.get('text')
            #functionality...
        return render(request, 'index.html',{'form':form}) 
    else:
        form = MyForm()
        return render(request, 'index.html',{'form':form})
```

Please may you show me how this can be done?

Comment: Is [`login_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) enough?

Comment: thank you Mathias, that was the hint I needed. I'll post the fudge I came up with below for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Mathias gave me the answer that the @login_required decorator would work, I added it to the form view so that in views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def form_handle(request):
    form = MyForm()
    #as above
```

Running this gave the error "Page not found (404)...The current URL, accounts/login/, didn't match any of these." So I changed the url pattern for IndexView to:

```
url(r'accounts/login/', IndexView.as_view())
```

and now it works. This is a hacky solution though and I still don't fully understand what is going on behind the scenes with TemplateView / how the views interact, in a way that would allow me to build better websites in the future. So if anyone has a better answer I'd be happy to accept that.