# Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted using django

Tags: python, django

hello i am user python and Django.

i will follow this [question(Can I have a Django form without Model)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17754295/can-i-have-a-django-form-without-model) 
but for my task i need images.
i will try to run my code and i have this error Forbidden (403) : any idea how to fix that ?

```
Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
You are seeing this message because this site requires a CSRF cookie when submitting forms. This cookie is required for security reasons, to ensure that your browser is not being hijacked by third parties.
If you have configured your browser to disable cookies, please re-enable them, at least for this site, or for 'same-origin' requests.
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from blog.forms import MyForm

# Create your views here.
def form_handle(request):
    form = MyForm()
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = MyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            #now in the object cd, you have the form as a dictionary.
            a = cd.get('a')
    return render_to_response('blog/calc.html', {'form': form}, RequestContext(request))
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class MyForm(forms.Form): #Note that it is not inheriting from forms.ModelForm
    a = forms.ImageField()
    #All my attributes here
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$',views.form_handle, name='form_handle'),

]
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In your view, when rendering your template, pass `RequestContext` as a keyword argument. `return render_to_response('blog/calc.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))`

Comment: Any particular reason for using`render_to_response('blog/calc.html', {'form': form}, RequestContext(request))` and not just `render(request, 'blog/calc.html', {'form': form}`?

Comment: the `render(request, 'blog/calc.html', {'form': form})` not work i take that error  ` ValueError: The view blog.views.form_handle didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead`

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a csrf token to the form, but not providing it in the view function.  Try this:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect

# Create your views here.
@csrf_protect
def form_handle(request):
    form = MyForm()
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the **@csrf_exempt** decorator to your view function.

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def my_func(request):
    pass
```

Comment: make sure that this is what you want if you are going to run this in production

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).