# Coding mental block with specific Django task

Tags: python, django

I've been thinking of this for a LONG time the past few days and can't figure out with my current toolset how to implement this in Django.

What I want is something that can be implemented trivially in Java for example, but how I'd do that on the web is much more difficult

**The problem**

I want to send data to a HTML template, specific example:

"What is 5 + 50?"

The data must be dynamically generated, so the 5 and 50 are actually randomly generated.

I think I am comfortable doing this part, as I'd simply pass a random variable to a template using the views.py

**This is where I do not know how to proceed**

I want the user to be able to enter their answer, *and* have them notified if it correct.

To do this, I'd need to pass the variables from the template back to another view function. I am not sure how to do that, if it is possible at all.

This is how I'm deciding to pursue my projecti dea, and I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way

tl;dr I just wanted data to be randomly generated and calculated using Django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pure django solution would be:

- create a form with three integer fields (say, `num1`, `num2` and `result`)
- in your view, populate `num1` and `num2` with the numbers to be added
- render the form in your template (`num1` and `num2` fields should be read only)
- the user enters the answer in the `result` field and submits the form
- in your view, determine whether `num1 + num2 == result`
- redirect to a success page if the answer is correct, otherwise redisplay the form

Comment: I didn't know you could make forms without a Model. Would it be something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17754295/can-i-have-a-django-form-without-model

Comment: Thanks will try implementing it tomorrow. Happy new years