# Implementing Django Form without Model

Tags: python, django

This is a continuation from last question here [Coding mental block with specific Django task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48041129/coding-mental-block-with-specific-django-task)

The answer was:

A pure django solution would be:

- create a form with three integer fields (say, `num1`, `num2` and `result`)
- in your view, populate `num1` and `num2` with the numbers to be added
- render the form in your template (`num1` and `num2` fields should be read only)
- the user enters the answer in the `result` field and submits the form
- in your view, determine whether `num1 + num2 == result`
- redirect to a success page if the answer is correct, otherwise redisplay the form

However, as I am working through the steps, my form was not being rendered properly.

views.py

```
def form_handle(request):
    form = MyForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            a = cd.get('a')
    return render(request, "rr.html", {})
```

forms.py

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    a = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    mat = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
```

html file

```
  <form action="{% url 'form_handle' %}" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
      {{form.as_p}}
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

When I load the page all I see is a submit button. [As pictured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWDZj.png)

Can someone please advise me where I had gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like below:
if form is valid then check for the condition otherwise post blank form;
if form is valid but result answer is wrong then redirect to previous url you desire to redirect

```
def form_handle(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyForm(request.POST) # if post method then form will be validated
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            num1 = cd.get('num1')
            num2 = cd.get('num2')
            result = cd.get('result')
            if float(num1) + float(num2) == float(result):
                # give HttpResponse only or render page you need to load on success
                return HttpResponse("valid entiries")
            else:
                # if sum not equal... then redirect to custom url/page 
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')  # mention redirect url in argument

    else:
        form = MyForm() # blank form object just to pass context if not post method
    return render(request, "rr.html", {'form': form})
```

Comment: Thank you for fixing my error, I see the issue now. !

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the `form` that you call in the html file is the `form` in the function `post_question` in views.py, isn't it? And where is the class `QuestionForm`?, can you show us the code of it? Because as I see, the class `MyForm` is still unused in file views.py. It would be easier if you also show us the import in views.py and the class `QuestionForm` instead of just a nonsensical `MyForm`. Cheer!

Comment: Hi I fixed my post up, I accidentally added the wrong views function. For the import statement, I did from .views import *, and from .forms import *