# how to do mapping input page(user) to view.py in django?

Tags: python, sql-server, django, django-forms, django-views

I am new to Django.Below is version of Django and used database

Django version:  2.1.15,
django-pyodbc-azure==1.11.9.0,
used sql-server 2012

django-admin start project item

> **Objective**: To take input from user @itemnumber & give that input to `EXEC ValidateBusinessrule '@itemnumber'` and show result in html page
>
> **setting.py** connection

```
DATABASES =\
    {
'default':
    {
    'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
    'NAME': 'ETP',
    'HOST': '10.*.*.*',
    'USER': '',
    'PASSWORD': '',

    'OPTIONS': {
                   'driver': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server',
               }
    }
}
```

> **item.urls:**

```
from django.urls import path
from django.urls import path from . import views
urlpatterns = [path(r'item/', views.itemnumber, name='index'), ] 
print("hello1")
```

> `UPDATION::::::::::::::::::::::::::::`

---

I am a newbie in Django and not able to map my user-input to my stored procedure query.

> views.py

```
from django.db import connection
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import InputForm
def home_view(request):
    print("woooooooooooo",request)
    context1 ={}

    context1['form']= InputForm()
    print("context1::::", context1)
    return render(request, "input.html", context1)

def itemnumber(request):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    try:
        itemnumber = "23241715"
        C=cursor.execute(f"EXEC ValidateBusinessrule '0000000000{itemnumber}'")
        print("c value",C)
        result_set = cursor.fetchall()
        print(result_set)
        result_set1= [' {} '.format(x) for x in result_set]
        print(result_set1)
        context = {"row": result_set1}
        print("lolllllllllll", context)
        return render(request, "home.html", context)
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        print("hello3")
```

> forms.py

```
from django import forms
import re
# creating a form
class InputForm(forms.Form):
    print("inside forms")
    regex = re.compile('^([1-9]{8})$', re.UNICODE)
    ENTER_ITEM_NUMBER= forms.RegexField(max_length=8, regex=regex,help_text=("Required 8 digits 
    between {0-9}."))
    print("iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii",ENTER_ITEM_NUMBER)
    #ENTER_ITEM_NUMBER = forms.IntegerField(max_length=8, label='ENTER ITEM NUMBER')
```

> item/urls

```
from django.urls import path
from django.urls import include, path
#from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [

    path('inputs/', views.home_view),
    path('item/', views.itemnumber, name='item'),
]
print("hello1")
```

> input.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action = "" method = "post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form }}
    <input type="submit" value=Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

> Home.html

```
 <html>
        <style>
                body
                {
                background-color: powderblue;
                }
            </style>
     <body>
        <table style="border: 1px solid #b50b32; margin: 30px auto; width: 100px; padding: 0; border-spacing: 10px;" bgcolor="#00FF00" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">
            <tr>
                <ul>
                    <th>(u,v)</th>

                </ul>
            </tr>
            <tr>

                <ul >
                    {% for row in row %}
                    <td style= "text-align: center;">
                        {{  row }}
                    </td>
                </ul>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
    </body>
 </html>
```

I am not using any model.*

> ([Can I have a Django form without Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17754295/can-i-have-a-django-form-without-model))

I got confused How can I give my **user input = ENTER_ITEM_NUMBER** to the **def itemnumber(request)**.

So that all things will work fine?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210519/discussion-on-question-by-yash-kumar-django-to-display-stored-procedure-result).

Answer (score 0):

Based on given example of code, I assume that your stored procedure takes string as an argument, so try executing `cursor.execute(f"EXEC ValidateBusinessrule '{itemnumber}'")`.

Upd: to pass resulting list to html template, consider using `render` method imported from `django.shorcuts`. More info on that [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/)

Comment: yes that worked.but it is in list format I want to convert that into table form with 2 columns

Comment: Well, it should return list of tuples, which is a table. In your html template you can iterate through this list and generate table view of it. To pass your list to html template you should use `render` method imported from `django.shortcuts`

Comment: not able to map my user-input to my stored procedure query.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is allowed by the code of conduct to remove your initial issue from question. That will make it harder to understand for people that will read this thread later, so please, consider to return your previous description and adding additional info under initial

Comment: ok thanks for information i will keep that in mind for future. I made a new thread for this . please visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60925818/how-to-do-mapping-user-input-page-to-view-py-in-django

Comment: To elaburate more, I am not able map input value submitted by user to itemnumber in def itemnumber(request) which is in view.py

Comment: you kinda edited question again. I recommend you to the 5th edition while I'll give a look at your new thread. Also, if my answer solved your initial issue, please, consider marking it as a solution to clarify it for others

Comment: upvoted.it says it is recroded, but as my reputation is less it will not show that.Please guide me for new thread.Thanks a lot for help buddy